# Now that not all method declarations in a Java Interface are public abstract, should the methods be declared with these modifiers?

Tags: java, coding-style, interfaces, coding-standards, keywords

Starting with Java 8, `default` methods were introduced into interfaces. Effectively, this means that not all methods in an `interface` are `abstract`.

Starting with Java 9 (maybe), `private` methods will be allowed. This means that not all methods in an `interface` are `public abstract`.

The question "Should methods in a Java interface be declared with or without the `public` access modifier?" was asked at Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161633/should-methods-in-a-java-interface-be-declared-with-or-without-a-public-access-m

There, most of the answers argued that `public abstract` should not be used because no method in an `interface` can be anything other than `public abstract`. That is no longer the case.

So, in light of these new features of interfaces, should the `public abstract` keywords be used in a Java interface method declaration?

In my specific environment, we will have people who are experienced software engineers, but not experienced in Java, reading Java code from time to time. I feel that leaving out the `public abstract` keywords will now create an additional point of confusion for those not familiar with the history of how interfaces came to have different rules for using these keywords.

Comment: did you check Java 8 JLS? [Same section as in old accepted answer at SO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) suggests that introduction of default methods didn't change prior recommendation which was based on the same redundancy considerations: "An interface method lacking a `default` modifier or a `static` modifier is implicitly `abstract`... It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the `abstract` modifier for such a method declaration." Why do you expect that things should change?

Comment: I thought things might change because the condition for a method to be implicitly `abstract` are becoming increasingly convoluted. In Java 9, that same sentence might be, "An interface method lacking a `default` modifier or a `static` modifier or a `private` modifier is implicitly abstract..."

Additionally, the auxiliary arguments for not explicitly using the keywords, namely, that all interface methods are `public abstract`, are now moot.

Comment: TBH I don't understand the reasoning behind "default" methods, and even static methods reach outside the scope of what interfaces are normally intended to do. Interfaces aren't supposed to be saddled with concretion. That's why they're useful types for references.

Comment: @TrixieWolf default methods allow interfaces to evolve. Previously, and unlike classes, adding a method would break every implementation; now, you can grow an interface as long as you have a good candidate default. Consider the addition of  `stream` to `java.util.Collection`, or `Map.getOrDefault()`. Alternative is to create a new sub-interface, and get everyone to downcast, like Graphics2D, and nobody enjoyed that!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the StackOverflow answer:

1. The `public` access modifier is not needed because

   > **Every method declaration** in the body of an interface **is implicitly public** (§6.6). It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public modifier for a method declaration in an interface. ([Section 9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4))
2. The `abstract` access modifier is not needed because

   > A default method is a method that is declared in an interface with the **default modifier;** its **body** is always **represented by a block**.

   And...

   > An interface method **lacking a default modifier** or a static modifier is **implicitly abstract**, so its **body is represented by a semicolon**, not a block.

Given that default methods *have* a body, and those that don't are inherently abstract, and every method declaration on an interface is inherently public, you don't need to specify either keyword.

---

One of the comments on an answer said:

> Don't make them think! I always added public abstract before, despite the style police, cause it made things clear and reminded the reader. Now I am vindicated because Java 8 and 9 complicate things (user949300)

A comment on the StackOverflow question (up-voted 18 times) refutes this:

> It's bad because writing it as public implies that it can be non-public (Pacerier)

The implications of code, especially interfaces, are important.

Comment: The comment you quoted from StackOverflow is now outdated. Saying that adding the public modifier is bad writing since it implies it can be non-public is contradictory. The method can be non-public.

Comment: @DavidCampbell: Well, I think this question might be better asked after Java 9 comes out. :) The as-of-yet-to-be-finalized Java spec might answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the lack of a block statement implication enough? Would you declare `extends Object` albeit it's implied?

If the developer does not understand the redundancy, chances are ***they might not fully understand the concept behind the language feature***, which is an even bigger problem than being confused about modifiers.

The developer must understand that the purpose of an interface is to create a contract that defines how a client can interact with an object. This suggests any method in an interface *used for object interaction* should be exposed to clients.

If you declare a method private, you are explicitly stating that method is not meant to be called by clients, which in the case of interfaces is something that can't easily be inferred.

Comment: Don't make them think!  I always added `public abstract` before, despite the style police, cause it made things clear and reminded the reader.  Now I am vindicated because Java 8 and 9 complicate things  :-). Java is plenty redundant already.

Comment: @user949300 Would you also add `extends Object` to every class that directly derives from `Object`? It's information a developer should already be aware of, which is why it's inferred. The less useless information on the screen, the easier it is to process the important information. Hopefully I've persuaded you to come to the dark side (Get it? Cause implicit stuff can't be seen). If not, it was worth a shot haha. In the end, it comes down to what makes the code easier to manage for the developer

Comment: @user949300 By doing this you are more likely to create confusion about what it means when interface methods don't contain these declarations.  i.e. if there are any developers learning java by looking at your code, you've potentially hobbled their understanding of the syntax of interface declarations.

Comment: Vince, no, I wouldn't extend Object, though I don't throw a fit when I see code that does so.  @JimmyJames, if one is consistent adding public abstract to items that are so, I don't see any confusion.  Am I missing something?  OTOH, I do see your point on clutter.  For example, I don't add `final` before method arguments unless something funny requires it (like an anonymous inner class etc...)

Comment: @user949300 He means if a user was already exposed to the lack of modifiers and the reason behind it, they may question why the modifiers are there when they see them, making them assume there may be an actual reason behind it other than just being explicit. I wouldn't throw a fit if I saw `extends Object`, but it would definitely raise a flag and make me question why. As I mentioned in the post, doing such things could imply that the developer may have a misunderstanding of how something works (may not know that all objects already extend `Object`, hence the explicit extension)

Comment: @user949300 Oops, he was saying the opposite (which is actually an worse problem than what I described) but the same idea still applies: it will throw off developers using your code. An experienced developer would question why it's there, a beginner who has been using it from day 1 will be confused about what the lack of modifiers represent as soon as they're exposed to it.

Comment: @user949300 In a normal Java class, a lack of modifiers means package-protected and not-abstract.  If a developer has never seen an interface where the methods are left without modifiers, they might not realize that this means public and abstract in the context of interfaces.  I don't want to make a mountain out of a molehill here but I think adding the redundant modifiers obscure the nature of interfaces more than they help.

Comment: Vonce and Jimmy, the beginner who gets confused when others leave off the `public abstract` will appreciate those "thoughtful" coders who always put it in for clarity. :-)  I can't see the experienced programmer being thrown off either.  If you see old style code `List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>()` do you say "oh no, I'm confused, why did he put in the second <Foo>?  No, you say "either that's old code, or that programmer stuck with that style".

Comment: @user949300 An experienced user would question whether it's redundant in the environment it exists in. Is it there for static analysis reasons, and would removing it cause analysis problems? If you feel being explicit is thoughtful, why wouldn't you declare `extends Object`? Where do you draw the line between too explicit and not explicit enough?

Comment: @user949300 "not making people think" and teaching don't really go together.  If new developer sees only interfaces declared in a clean sparse way, they will be forced to figure out how it really works early on.  The danger period for learning any skill is when people know a little bit but some of what they think they know is wrong.  Adding redundant cruft annoys many but helps no one.

Comment: "*Forced to learn how it really works early on*" - How is that a problem? If they're going to use it, they *should* know how it fully works. Otherwise they risk abusing the feature. IMO, a question like this would only arise if "a beginner who doesn't understand the feature wants to use the feature" pops to mind, which is a deeper problem.

Comment: @Vince, normally I'd agree with you. However, these default and private methods are breaking the purpose of the interface. In the end, I think we may end up banning the use of default and private methods in an interface. It seems that Oracle didn't understand the purpose of the interface when they added these modifications.